# Unix exception when starting flow-bin on FreeBSD

Tags: flowtype, freebsd

FreeBSD has a Linux compatibility layer, so I'd expect flow-bin to be able to run on it. Alas, I got an exception after tagging the linux bin as linux elf:

> Unhandled exception: Unix.Unix_error(Unix.EACCESS, "open", "/dev/null")

But /dev/null has proper permissions:

```
crw-rw-rw- root wheel
```

Or? Setting it to 777 does not help.

Edit: running as root, still fails, log shows "Out of shared memory" from a Hack library? I'm assuming this specific library does *not* work on FreeBSD, being to low-level perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, most programs running under Linuxulator require following pseudo-FSes mounted:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
<...snip...>
linprocfs   /compat/linux/proc  linprocfs       rw      0       0
tmpfs    /compat/linux/dev/shm  tmpfs   rw,mode=1777    0       0
```

I suspect, the latter line should fix your second problem.

As for the permission error, you should check not `/dev/null`, but `/compat/linux/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks! Changing permission on compat dev null works. How would I mount the tmpfs...?

Comment: Now it says memfd_create not implemented.

Comment: Ok, someone on IRC said memfd_create is implemented in CURRENT.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt If you have a new question open one. Do not ask different questions here in the comments section. [ask]